# return index on modify event

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a LineString feature inside Open Layers and plot two points. When I click and drag to add a point between the two existing points, is there a property or an event that gets triggered to tell me the Index of the new point?

At the moment i have tried the following two events:

```
session.Modify.on('modifystart', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});

session.Modify.on('modifyend', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

These both return the new coordinates but doesn't tell me that I inserted between index 0 and 1.

Is there anyway I can find this out?

Comment: I don't think so.  You might study https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/2e1495fc07e19ebf47def135719a2461cbf891c5/src/ol/interaction/modify.js#L550.  Seems `dragSegments_` has what you're looking for.